# GAS external user autentication

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

We are a italian municipality, we have to start a google site to let the people to signal  city issues.

Unauthenticated users can post or view issues,
Google domain's authenticated users, can edit some information.

For some categories,  external companies are engaged for solution, these aren't google domain's  users,  but we need to let them edit the information as the authenticated users ...

Is there a way to authenticate an external user to Google domain?
Or a way to recognise the user working on a google site?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invite users who do not have a google account to be a site editor.  This is done with the standard site share settings.  An email will be sent to the users email you added with a link with an access token.  The user will have to click that link to open the page in edit mode.

If a user shares this link it is effectively sharing his editing rights to your site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I just tested your solution: invited my external mail account, I had to create a new free google account then i can edit the pages... but it was'nt the matter!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I just tested your solution: invited my external mail account, I had to create a new free google account then i can edit the pages... but it wasn't the matter!! I need my google apps script know who is the user to let him edit some fields.

Comment: There arn't field level permissions. Only page or site.

Comment: I figured that it was not possible to authenticate users outside our domain, I worked around the problem by using an additional query string parameter. Thanks for confirming